# How to reset board for tic tac toe in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, tic-tac-toe

```
function resetBoard() {
    currentPlayer = 1;
    isGameStarted = false;
    gameBoard = [
        [null, null, null],
        [null, null, null],
        [null, null, null]
    ];

    const startButton = document.getElementById("start-btn");
    startButton.disabled = false;

    const playerNames = document.querySelectorAll(".player-name");
    playerNames.forEach(name => name.classList.remove("active"));

    const cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");
    cells.forEach(cell => {
        cell.textContent = "";
        cell.classList.add("disabled");
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "#d7bbf7";
    });

    const resultDiv = document.getElementById("current-player");
    resultDiv.textContent = "";

    const messageDiv = document.getElementById("message");
    messageDiv.textContent = "";

    const gameBoardDiv = document.getElementById("game-board");
    gameBoardDiv.style.display = "none";

    player1Name = "";
    player2Name = "";
    document.getElementById("player1-name").textContent = "Player 1";
    document.getElementById("player2-name").textContent = "Player 2";
}


function makeMove(row, col) {
    if (!isGameStarted) return;

    const cell = document.querySelector(`.row:nth-child(${row + 1}) .cell:nth-child(${col + 1})`);
    if (cell.textContent !== "") return;

    if (currentPlayer === 1) {
        cell.textContent = "X";
        gameBoard[row][col] = "X";
    } else if (currentPlayer === 2) {
        cell.textContent = "O";
        gameBoard[row][col] = "O";
    }

    if (checkWin()) {
        const resultDiv = document.getElementById("message");
        resultDiv.textContent = "You won, " + getCurrentPlayerName() + "!";
        isGameStarted = false;
        resetBoard();
    } else if (checkDraw()) {
        const resultDiv = document.getElementById("message");
        resultDiv.textContent = "It's a draw!";
        isGameStarted = false;
        resetBoard();
    } else {
        currentPlayer = currentPlayer === 1 ? 2 : 1;
        const resultDiv = document.getElementById("current-player");
        resultDiv.textContent = "It's your turn " + getCurrentPlayerName();
    }
}
```

Why my function resetBoard() doesn't work? i.e. it does work but when I finish one game it doesn't let me see result, if it's either draw or it has winner, but it immediately reset board. I wanna now why this is happening and how to fix this, if someone is willing to help.

Comment: You call `resetBoard()` as soon as there is a winner or a draw. You should reset it with a button.

Comment: We're willing to help, but you have to do some work too. First thing to do is to create a [mre]. The rest you can read in [ask].

Comment: I already posted the cause and solution with explanation, just check it and ask if it does not solves the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

That's quite simple. But to understand what the problem is let's talk about the structure in which your code runs:

#### Flow

1. Make move
2. Check for result
3. [Win/Draw] -> `resultDiv.textContent = "Whatever the result is"`
4. ResetBoard -> `resultDiv.textContent = "";` *(line 23)*

So what's happening here is, your code does set the result but right after setting result, it resets board which resets the result div's content

### Solutions

#### Solution 1

Every problem has multiple solutions. But what the easiest solution here I think is that instead of resetting the board right after the game ends, just show the result, hide the board, and show a button that'll reset the board on click. This not only solves the issue but also improve the UX

```html
<button onclick="resetBoard()">Play Again</button>
```

#### Solution 2:

if you did not like the one above then, you can use alert box to show the message/result

#### Solution 3:

Another solution would be to remove the text only after a move is made instead of during board reset. i.e. Don't remove text in `resetBoard()`, instead, remove the text in `makeMove()`.

Comment: I think solution 1 will help, but I have one question. I already defined start-btn in my html and I would like to use that for reset board also. To clarify this, when I click start-btn game starts and when game is finished and I again click that exact same button it restart board. I hope you understand and thanks for helping, I'm new in this.

Comment: I'd suggest not doing that (same button doing multiple things), rather manipulate the DOM (toggle between the start and reset btn as needed - Post separate question for separate problems). also, @anonimous23 if my code helps then **accept it as answer** by clicking on the tick mark

Comment: Okay, thanks for all your effort!

Comment: Just to let you know, I solved this with your solution. Thanks again! @Hind Sagar Biswas